# How can I find out if a specific character in a QString is a letter or punctuation?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

How can I find out if a specific character in a QString is a letter or punctuation in any language?

For example I want to find the `.` in `gâteau.` but not the `â`.

Comment: In which  language you are working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
str.at(i).isLetter()
```

It will return true for the unicode classes Letter_Uppercase/Lowercase/Titlecase/Modifier/Other. Which you can see here:

http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/lu.html

http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/ll.html

http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/lt.html

http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/lm.html

http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/lo.html

Answer (score 2):

You can get a QChar out of a QString using at(), and QChar has a isLetter() function.  Thus, you want something like:

```
QString myString;
if (myString.at(3).isLetter()) {
   qDebug() << "letter number 4 in the string is a letter";
}
```