# Check if last character of a string is a letter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I check if the last character of value is any letter without comparing it manually with each letter?

```
   if(value.endsWith("A",Qt::CaseInsensitive)==true)
   ...
```

This is my code so far, Value has to start with Y/X/Z and have 9 characters

```
 void Extranjero::setNIE(const QString &value)
{


    if(value.startsWith("Y",Qt::CaseInsensitive)==true && value.length()==9)
    {
    NIE = value;
    }
    else if(value.startsWith("X",Qt::CaseInsensitive)==true && value.length()==9)
    {
    NIE = value;
    }
    else if(value.startsWith("Z",Qt::CaseInsensitive)==true && value.length()==9)
    {
    NIE = value;
    }

    else NIE = "Problemon";
}
```

Comment: why not using `std::isalpha`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611815/determine-if-char-is-a-num-or-letter it asks for both letters and digits, but the answers should be adjustable easily

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the isalpha() function

Comment: The classic is `if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z'))`. That covers only uppercase though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -- it may be "classic", but it's wrong. For example, it won't work when the character encoding is EBCDIC.

Comment: I believe this is much better duplicate candidate since it actually works for QString: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231746/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-specific-character-in-a-qstring-is-a-letter-or-punctuati

Answer (score 0):

You can use `back()` and `begin()` member functions.

```
if(value.length() == 9){
  QChar tmpChar = value.back();
  if( tmpChar == 'Z' || tmpChar == 'Y' || tmpChar == 'Z'){
   // code..
  }
}
```

Comment: OP: "... without comparing it manually with each letter?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want your string to end with any alphabetic character, then you can easily use `isalpha`.
However, in the other case when you want it to start with specific characters like 'X', 'Y' or 'Z', then you need to manually specify them.
In order to generalize your code for the latter case, I recommend inserting your specific characters in a set and just check if this set contains the first character of the given string.
I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about isalpha() function, now I only need to split my string into a char array to check it.

Comment: @Yassin Note that `isalpha` is only suited for regular ascii `char`s. QChar has a [isLetter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#isLetter) function that is much better suited. Unless you only need to check against [a-zA-Z].

Comment: @Yassin If my answer helps you, kindly accept it.